# Unite multiple tables into a single one using union and a loop operator in Kusto

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am pretty new to **Azure Data Explorer (Kusto)** queries. I have a [stored function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/schema-entities/stored-functions), that takes a dateTime as a parameter, does some querying around that dateTime and return a data table.

```
MyStoredFunction(timestamp:datetime){
 // some query 
}
```

For several limitations I have to run this function several times, with consecutive datetimes with a one-hour interval between each, then unite the result as a single table using the [union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unionoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer) operator.

```
ResultTable
| union MyStoredFunction(now(-1h))
, MyStoredFunction(now(-2h))
, MyStoredFunction(now(-3h))
, MyStoredFunction(now(-4h))
, MyStoredFunction(now(-5h))
, MyStoredFunction(now(-6h))
| Project column1, column2, column3
| Summarize …
```

Is there a way to beatify the above ugly query using the [range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/rangeoperator) operator or any other Kusto query operators?

Something like this (the bellow query is not valid, it's just for illustration):

> range TIMESTAMP from now(-7h) to now() step 1h
> | ResultTable  = union ResultTable, MyStoredFunction(TIMESTAMP)

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not possible.

The [union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unionoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer) operator supports wildcards, but only for actual tables and not results of function executions.